# Get the 2 byte representation of a number in php

Tags: php

I need to convert an integer to a 2 byte binary in PHP. dechex does part of the job but problem is it outputs a string.

Example:

```
1 = \x01
2 = \x2c
```

the output should not be a string but rather a raw byte that I needs to send over a socket using fwrite()

Comment: I think `pack` might be a good option: https://3v4l.org/0EId6. Make sure to watch endianess

Comment: What do you mean by "2 byte binary"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.